# JFreechart: Imposing continuous and dashed series line

Tags: jfreechart

I am using an XYStepRenderer to draw a graph with two series. One series is represented with a continuous line and the other is represented via a dashed line. The result is like this:
[image]

Problem here is that at the right side of the graph, the continuous line completely hides the dashed line.

I would rather like the result to be like this (the dashed line is 'in front' and the gaps between the dashes are transparant):
[image]

How can I do this with jfreechart.

Thanks for the assistance,

Frederik.

Comment: Does it help to change the order of adding the `XYSeries` to the collection?

Comment: Seems to change the graph indeed. If i add the dashed line first, then it gives the desired result. Thanks !

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117325).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can do either of these:

- Change the order of adding each `XYSeries` to the `XYSeriesCollection`, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025862/261156).
- Change the order of calling `setSeriesStroke()`, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025862/261156) and suggest [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117325).